# callback function parsing JSON in JQuery

Tags: jquery, json, google-app-engine, getjson

I'm new to JQuery and maybe this is a n00b question. And also my English is not the best.

I wrote a service in my Google App Engine application who delivers data in JSON format, which works OK, but I wasn't able to parse that JSON data using JQuery:

```
var url= 'myapp.appspot.com/myservice.json?someparams';
$.getJSON(url, function(json){
    alert("Success parsing JSON");  // I never reached this code 
    ....
});
```

After a few days of reading posts and tutorials I felt into this SlideShare: http://www.slideshare.net/andymckay/cross-domain-webmashups-with-jquery-and-google-app-engine

While reading slide 23 I noticed about the "callback=?" parameter and I tried the code in slide 42:

```
class MyJSONHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        ## Retrieve some data from DB or MemCached
        jsonData = json.dumps(data)
        if self.request.get('callback'):
            self.response.out.write('%s(%s)' % (self.request.get('callback'), jsonData))
        else:
            self.response.out.write(jsonData)
```

And in the JQuery function:

```
$.getJSON(url+'&callback=?', function(json){
    alert("Success parsing JSON");  // Now i'm here !!
    ....
});
```

My question is:

Why is the "callback" parameter necessary to make this work? What difference does the '?("MyJSON": [{"a-lot" : "of-data"}])' makes??

Thanks you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `callback` parameter is used to implement [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP).

jQuery's `getJSON` method creates a `<script>` tag that point to the URL you give it.
The URL is expected to return a call to the function specified in the `callback` parameter, passing the data as a parameter.

Unlike normal AJAX requests, JSONP requests can be made across domains.

Answer (score 1):

If you are accessing your service from another domain using AJAX, the browser won't allow that. Using this technique gets around it by dynamically embedding a script tag with the src attribute set to the requested URL, and the body of the script calls your function name passed in, passing it your data.

Here's a great explanation of the process: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP

Answer (score 0):

It's called JSONP.

You can look here: [What is JSONP all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/please-explain-jsonp)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The technique is called [*JSONP: JSON with Padding*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) and is used to circumvent the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).